# Javascript works as expected on Windows, errors on Linux

Tags: javascript, linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a script that parses through an xml file and copies an image path field to a new file. It works exactly as intended on a windows machine using the bash terminal. I tested it on a Ubuntu machine with the exact same code and xml files, and I am getting a TypeError. Here's where it is giving me trouble on Ubuntu:

```
if (catalogLine.indexOf('<image path="') !== -1){
    //if we have an image, read the image file list line by line
    var imageCount = 0;
    var image = '';
    var whitespace = catalogLine.match(/^\s*/)[0].length;
    lineReader.eachLine(resources.fileListToCompare, function(imageLine, imageLast, imageCB) {
        if (catalogLine.indexOf(imageLine) !== -1) {
            //if we match an image, make a copy and store outside of scope
            imageCount++;
            image = ' '.repeat(whitespace) + '<image path="' + imageLine + '"/>';
        }
```

And here is the traceback:

```
/vagrant/ChalkTalkTool/ImageRemoval.js:23
                            image = ' '.repeat(whitespace) + '<image path="' + imageLine + '"/>'
                                        ^
TypeError: Object   has no method 'repeat'
at /vagrant/ChalkTalkTool/ImageRemoval.js:23:17
at /vagrant/ChalkTalkTool/node_modules/line-reader/lib/line_reader.js:277:11
at getLine (/vagrant/ChalkTalkTool/node_modules/line-reader/lib/line_reader.js:166:7)
at Object.nextLine (/vagrant/ChalkTalkTool/node_modules/line-reader/lib/line_reader.js:183:7)
at Object.readNext [as _onImmediate] (/vagrant/ChalkTalkTool/node_modules/line-reader/lib/line_reader.js:269:14)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:363:15)
```

So I see that the error is in the line:

```
image = ' '.repeat(whitespace) + '<image path="' + imageLine + '"/>';
```

I can assume that it has do with the empty space character, but I want to understand why this happens on Ubuntu, and a way around it so that I can make my code more portable across different systems (I have tried using the character

```
"&nbsp;"
```

instead of a space to no avail).

Comment: Maybe it has issues between MS line-endings and UNIX line-endings?

Comment: @evolutionxbox that's what I would assume is the issue from the traceback, I just wonder if there's a method to get around that issue

Comment: What version of Node is your Linux machine running? (`node --version`)

Comment: This is, presumably, NodeJS?  Are you certain you are using the same version of NodeJS on the two different OSes?

Comment: `" ".repeat(10)` works fine on Linux with Node 7.4.0. The error is basically telling you that there's no `.repeat()` function on either the String or Object prototypes; it has nothing to do with line terminator characters.

Comment: @Pointy the Linux machine is running 0.10.48 and windows is running v5.0.0. That could be the issue. I have nvm on Ubuntu, I will test that out

Comment: That's **definitely** the issue. The Ubuntu platform generally does not try to remain current with software development platforms like Node. It's often safer to install things like that directly from the source instead of `apt-get`.

Comment: @Pointy you are correct. So that means that in the version I was using on ubuntu, and most likely other versions, the `.repeat()` function does not exist for String or Object prototypes, as you mentioned

Comment: @Pointy that makes complete sense, that's why i installed nvm as a workaround because of issues I had from the beginning with the node version and dependencies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the repeat() function is only available in ES6 and higher.  I'm assuming the Ubuntu instance you have running is running ES5.

You can test this theory by installing a polyfill, or write one yourself at the top of your code:

```
if (!String.prototype.repeat) {
  String.prototype.repeat = function(howManyTimes) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < howManyTimes; i++) {
      result += this;
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```